# Capture Get-ChildItem results into string array for HTML output

Tags: string, powershell, split

I'm writing a PowerShell script and I want to capture the list of files in a directory and store into a variable. Once captured I'd like to print it to an HTML file.  I've captured the data like this:

```
$listDownloads = Get-ChildItem -Force "C:\Users\Someuser\Downloads"
```

Now, I want to convert `$listDownloads` into a string and split it. How do I go about doing that?

I've tried this:

```
$listSplit = $listDownloads.ToString().Split(" ")
```

but I get this output:

```
System.Object[]
```

**Updated:**

```
$html = '<html>'
$body = '<body>'
$p = '<p>'
$pClose = '</p>'
$StatusDownloads = 'Directory of the Downloads Folder'
$pTags = $p.ToString() + $StatusDownloads + $pClose.ToString();
$listDownloads = (Get-ChildItem -Force "C:\Users\Someuser\Downloads").Name;




function createHTML($addtoFile){

   $addtoFile | Add-Content 'status.html'

}

function printData($printData){

    Write-Output $printData
}


$html | Set-Content 'status.html'

createHTML($html)
createHTML($body)
createHTML($pTags)
createHTML($listDownloads)
```

When I try to print $listDownloads it gives me the data all on the same line (i.e. File 1 File 2) I want each file or folder displayed on a new line. How would I do that? If I were to type Get-ChildItem -Force "C:\Users\Someuser\Downloads" into Powershell it would give the list of files line by line. I want that type of output on my HTML page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I can think you want to split is to get an array of filenames.

If that's the case, you can do:

```
$list = (Get-ChildItem -Force "C:\Users\Someuser\Downloads").FullName
```

From your update you would need to pass into your function as:

```
createHTML($listDownloads -join "`n")
```

Comment: When I try to display $list it gives me System.Object[]

Comment: I still can't convert and split it into strings. It give mes String.Object[]

Comment: @CharlesWhitfield It's already split into strings. What are you actually _trying_ to do? You only need this one line to get an array of filenames in `$list`. If you're getting `String.Object[]` you must be doing something else on top of that

Comment: Good job inferring what the OP wanted. `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName` would have also have worked. Albeit a little more verbose

Comment: Its an object array that contains strings. If you look at the individual elements it is System.String. Suppose you could cast as a string array if you really had to: `[string[]]((Get-ChildItem -Force "C:\Users\Someuser\Downloads").FullName)`

Comment: @arco444 - I'm trying to write the data to an HTML file, however it shows the output in one line i.e (File 1 File 2) I want each file name on a new line, as if you typed into Powershell.

Comment: @Matt - How would I print the data?

Comment: @CharlesWhitfield - don't you need `<br>` tags or some other html stuff then? You need to update the question, describe exactly what you're doing and include more code.